# Rogue sorcerer archetype

Tags: character-creation, sorcerer, pathfinder-2e

I am not sure I understand how this works.  I have a rogue that gets the sorcerer archetype via the Ancient Elf heritage (Lost Omens Character Guide).

Because of the heritage, he automatically gets the 'Sorcerer Dedication' archetype feat.  That feat gives him two cantrips (he chose occult).

So as he gains levels he gets nothing more until he takes another sorcerer archetype feat, right?

If he later chooses 'Basic Sorcerer Spellcasting', he gets a first level slot, picks up a 2nd level spell at 6th character level, and a 3rd at 8th character level.  Right?

So, if he only chooses those two feats, at level 20 he gets 2 cantrips, 1- 1st, 1- 2nd, and 1- 3rd level spell?   Only 5 spells?

I get that it shouldn't be as good as a primary sorcerer, but a sorcerer main gets 5 cantrips and 3 first level spells.  At 20th level, a sorcerer main gets 42 spells, but our guy only gets 5.

Do I have that right?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 13):

### You are correct

[Sorcerer Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=734) (which you get as your Heritage bonus) gives you

- Two skills Trained, based on your Bloodline
- Two Cantrips
- Trained spell DC/Attack Proficiency (which scales with level as normal for proficiency)
- The ability to use [Wands](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=756) and [Scrolls](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=720) because you have a spell list
- The ability to use the cantrips of a [Staff](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=748)

Through [further *investment*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=170) into the Dedication, you can get:

- [Basic Sorcerer Spellcasting](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=735)

  - 1st, 2nd, and 3rd level spell slot (and spell known)
  - One of your known spells is a Signature spell
  - Access to level 1-3 spells on a Staff
- [Expert Sorcerer Spellcasting](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=740)

  - 4th, 5th, and 6th level spell slot (and spell known)
  - Two of your known spells are Signature spells
  - Expert spell DC/Attack Proficiency
  - Access to level 1-6 spells on a Staff
- [Master Sorcerer Spellcasting](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=741)

  - 7th and 8th level spell slot (and spell known)
  - Three of your known spells are Signature spells
  - Master spell DC/Attack Proficiency
  - Access to level 1-8 spells on a Staff

Each of these provide 3 (or 2 high level) spells per day at the cost of a [Class Feat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?Traits=139) slot. As a Rogue, this would be potentially losing something like [Dread Striker](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=561) (for example). It does not preclude access to any of the Rogue features, only limiting the number of Rogue Feats that you get.

Additionally, there is another Dedication Feat to provide more spell slots

- [Bloodline Breadth](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=739)

  - Increases your spell repertoire and spell slots except the top 2 (up to 6th level)

Full investment costs you 4 Class Feat slots (5 if you hadn't taken one as your Heritage) of your 11 total Class Feat choices to know 14 spells and have 14 slots per day to cast them, plus 2 Cantrips (and the ability to use items such as wands without spending a Skill Feat and action on [Trick Magic Item](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=857)). Obviously, you won't keep up with Spellcasters... but you aren't supposed to be. This is supplementary to your Rogue features.

Regardless of your feats invested, your DC will continue to increase with level as normal, so your spell attack/DC should be in the ballpark of +27(37) at level 20 with just the Dedication/Basic Spellcasting up to ~+31(41) if you also take Expert and Master Spellcasting (compared to a full Sorcerer's expected +34-35(44-45).

Whether or not it is worth it to you has a lot to do with your character concept and goals; do you care more about your Rogue Feats or the ability to expand on your sorcerous heritage and how much use can you get out of 8-14 spells per day vs the various Rogue Feat options (many of which are also situational)?